# How would you avoid "Xcode, Subversion Error: 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory)"?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I am not able to see the commit option after I make changes to my working copy, but I ensured that my settings for `svn` were correct.

What exactly is the problem with this error message?

Xcode is showing:

> Your path is not a working copy

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Subversion actually gave an error "ur path is not a working coppy"?

Comment: i was not able to update my project changes to svn ..
when i right click on my file is not showing commit changes option atleast is not showing M symbol......

Answer (score 6):

The blog post "[Xcode, Subversion Error: 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210180121/http://note19.com/2009/03/17/xcode-subversion-error-155007-path-is-not-a-working-copy-directory/)" and its comment are pretty much the reference on this kind of error.

**Simple Workaround**:

1. Delete your local copy (`cd myxcodeproject; rm -rf .`)
2. Delete the “`build`” folder from the server
3. `svn co https://svnserver/path/trunk/project .`

> Now you should see `.svn` folders in every directory of your local project (you don’t see them if you use the “`Export`” function of the SCM panel from Xcode).
>   At this point, you should be able to edit and commit your changes directly from Xcode.

Now you need to initialize correctly the project.
The following sections illustrate that part:

**How to do it right (general principle)**

> To place the project under Xcode, you need to first import it.
>   The `SCM->commit entire project…` gives error 155007 if you don’t first do this:
>
> Under the SCM menu in Xcode select Repositories, then click the IMPORT icon at the top of that dialog that appears.
>   Select the project from the list and then click the import button.
>
> Of course you need to first configure at least one repository before doing the steps above.

**Right Initialization steps (detailed process)**

> 1. Create the project in XCODE.
> 2. Setup subversion in XCODE and select the subversion repository for this project.
> 3. Use Xcode SCM > Repository and click on the IMPORT icon. This will move the local copy to the subversion repository.
> 4. Now delete your local copy (or move it to another location just in case).
> 5. Finally CHECKOUT the project from subversion (this will create the subversion .svn folders, …).
> 6. Reselect the subversion repository for this project.
> 7. Commit the entire project.

Comment: @Iak: It is a generic path to a SVN repository, given here as an example. It means you should checkout your SVN repository, replacing "`svnserver/path/trunk/project`" by your SVN repo path. Note the fine dot, which indicates you are checkouting the SVN repo at the current path ('`myxcodeproject`' here, again a generic directory name given as an example).