# Xcode and SVN: can't rename my class -> Error: 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory)

Tags: svn, xcode

I get the following error, if I try to rename my class:

> **Error During Rename**
>
> Error: 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory) Description: Path 'xxx/Classes/MyClass.h' is not a directory

The renaming looks like this:
MyClass.h -> MYClass.h

Perhaps that is the problem?

I've made an initial import to my SVN directory. This is working so far (deleting, committing, etc.) The only thing it can't is renaming a class.

I tried:

> 4.Now delete your local copy (or move it to another location just in case).
>
> 5.Finally CHECKOUT the project from subversion (this will create the subversion .svn 
>   folders, …).
>
> 6.Reselect the subversion repository for this project.
>
> 7.Commit the entire project.

There is also no `build` directory in the SVN directory. The one thing which stands out is that I can't see any .svn folder. I'm using Xcode 3.2.3. The file I'm trying to rename/refactor is in the classes folder. I tried to delete a file from the classes folder and it worked!

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219695/how-would-you-avoid-xcode-subversion-error-155007-path-is-not-a-working-copy). I also found a similar [problem](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1700140). But there is no solution available so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same problem and Google directed me to this question, so apologies for the late 'answer'.

Anyhow, I'm working on eclipse 3.5, mac osx snow leopard, and you seem to be working on mac os x as well (xcode)? The point is, that mac osx' hfs+-filesystem is most of the time setup case-insensitively, so since you're only trying to change the case of your filenames this could be your problem.

The workaround for me was to perform the rename from FOO.h to Foo.h as:

- FOO.h -> FooBar.h
- FooBar.h -> Foo.h

(N.B. currently, all file renames in which only the case changes are giving the same problem on my system)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here **MyClass.h** -> **MYClass.h** It seems that this isn't supported by the SVN or Xcode ...

Option 1: No refactoring

Option 2: Delete the file and create a new one

I chose option No. 2. I'll try to post an instruction:

> 1. Go to SCM > Repositories. Select only one file. Click the Delete button. Do this as often as you need.
> 2. Go to your files in Xcode. Make your renaming/refactoring of the names in the files. Then copy content of your files temporary in TextEdit.
> 3. Select the files you want to delete in Xcode. Right-Click > Delete.
> 4. Create your new Class/Files and copy the content of TextEdit into these files.
> 5. Go to SCM > SCM Results. Select all files (inclusive myProject.xcodeproj). Confirm add and delete of the files.
> 6. Than make a commit of all changed files.
> 7. Press the Reload button in the Repositories window to see if the files are there.

The process looks like as described above. I had many problems getting things right. I hope now it is correct. I think the instructions above are not 100% correct, but I have done so many things that this is the only thing I can remember. Hope this will help someone else.

PS: I think add/delete/rename should not be done in Xcode. Only problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going to the command line, you can work around local case insensitivity with a server-side rename:

```
svn rename repo-URL/FOO.bar repo-URL/foo.bar -m "FOO.bar rename to Foo.bar"
```

Just for reference:
[svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re18.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your troubleshooting steps (where are steps 1 to 3?) but, assuming that:

1. `xxx/MyClass.h` is already under version control
2. Whey you say "rename class" you mean "rename file"
3. You're issuing a `svn rename` command

... then your working copy is probably corrupt. I've suffered from that problem before and there's not actual fix. I suggest you:

1. Check out a fresh working copy
2. Copy pending changes (if any) using a regular merge tool (like `WinMerge` or `TortoiseMerge`), being extremelly careful so you don't copy any `.svn` directory
3. Commit

Comment: Step 1 and 2 are already done (create Xcode project and configure SVN). Step 3 is the import, which I also have done, but I don't want make any new import yet (I think the import was successful and the problem is elsewhere). Yes, I mean renaming files (but it is actually renaming a class). I'm not issuing a `svn rename` command. I think that is done by Xcode, but I'll try that. I've already made five fresh working copies and it is every time the same result (perhaps there is a problem with the import but committing and deleting works?). I'm worrying all the time, where my .svn folders are.

Comment: Import? I hope you're creating a fresh *working copy* and not a new *repository*. Whatever, make sure Xcode supports file renames in SVN.

Comment: No import! Fresh working copy the tenth ... How do I find out what Xcode supports and what not? I experienced that Xcode is ****

Comment: To find out whether it supports renames, just make a rename with Xcode in a pristine working copy and then run `svn status` from the command line.